# Useless Git cache/index objects?

Tags: git

In preparation for a commit, I git add file f twice, only using it in its 2nd version with the commit. Can I remove version 1 of f from .git/objects? Does .git/objects contain "useless" copies of my git adds even when intermediate versions aren't ever committed? How can I do some clean-up?

Comment: Are you sure git keeps the first version anywhere? It seems quite logical for it throw away the previous added-uncommitted version of the file when you add the same file again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[git gc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) will run automatically for "some commands", but it also says:

> Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each repository to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating performance.

git gc will prune 2-week-old unreachable objects by default, but you can override that duration with the `--prune` option.

To specifically only remove unreachable objects, you can use [git prune](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-prune.html).  From its notes:

> In most cases, users will not need to call git prune directly, but should instead call git gc, which handles pruning along with many other housekeeping tasks.
>
> For a description of which objects are considered for pruning, see git fsck's `--unreachable` option.

Comment: I meant: I may want this clean-up to happen "now" (maybe accidentally included some content to be kept private..)